# How to use DEBUG flags in AOSP classes?

Tags: android, android-source

Sometimes in AOSP sources I see `private static final boolean` debug flag with `false` as ïts value. And there are debug output if this flag is `true`. Something like [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingTextHelper.java):

```
private static final boolean DEBUG_DRAW = false;
private static final Paint DEBUG_DRAW_PAINT;
static {
    DEBUG_DRAW_PAINT = DEBUG_DRAW ? new Paint() : null;
    if (DEBUG_DRAW_PAINT != null) {
        DEBUG_DRAW_PAINT.setAntiAlias(true);
        DEBUG_DRAW_PAINT.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    }
}
```

Who and how uses it? Is it possible to switch this flag somehow and take debug output of AOSP classes?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible with Java and [Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Pros:

- I don't think there is anything more powerfull than that

Cons:

- This technique will be executed at runtime so any code executed before this (e.g. classes loading)... well, is already executed. So you won't see the effects
- Slow at runtime
- **Dangerous**. Use it carefully

You can modify any value using this:

```
Class<?> klass = ...
Field field = klass.getDeclaredField("DEBUG_DRAW");
field.setAccesible(true);
field.set(
    null, // as this is an static attribute we don't need anything here...
    true  // set true as new value
);
```

As I stated before reflection is a dangerous technique so that snipped will throw several exceptions if used wrong so you will have to handle them